# parallel event subscriber .net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-4.5

I am trying to create a parallel event subscriber. This is my first attempt:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EventStore.ClientAPI;

namespace Sandbox
{
    public class SomeEventSubscriber
    {
        private Position? _latestPosition;
        private readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> _eventHandlerMapping;
        private IEventStoreConnection _connection;

        public Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> EventHandlerMapping
        {
            get { return _eventHandlerMapping; }
        }

        public SomeEventSubscriber()
        {
            _eventHandlerMapping = CreateEventHandlerMapping();
            _latestPosition = Position.Start;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            ConnectToEventstore();
        }

        private void ConnectToEventstore()
        {
            _connection = EventStoreConnectionWrapper.Connect();
            _connection.Connected +=
            (sender, args) => _connection.SubscribeToAllFrom(_latestPosition, false, EventOccured, LiveProcessingStarted, HandleSubscriptionDropped);
        }

        private Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> CreateEventHandlerMapping()
        {
            return new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>
            {
                {typeof (FakeEvent1), o => Handle(o as FakeEvent1)},
                {typeof (FakeEvent2), o => Handle(o as FakeEvent2)},
            };
        }

        private async Task Handle(FakeEvent1 eventToHandle)
        {
            SomethingLongRunning(eventToHandle);
        }

        private async Task Handle(FakeEvent2 eventToHandle)
        {
            SomethingLongRunning(eventToHandle);
        }

        private async Task SomethingLongRunning(BaseFakeEvent eventToHandle)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start Handling: " + eventToHandle.GetType());
            var task = Task.Delay(10000);
            await task;
            Console.WriteLine("Finished Handling: " + eventToHandle.GetType());
        }

        private void EventOccured(EventStoreCatchUpSubscription eventStoreCatchUpSubscription,
            ResolvedEvent resolvedEvent)
        {
            if (resolvedEvent.OriginalEvent.EventType.StartsWith("$") || resolvedEvent.OriginalEvent.EventStreamId.StartsWith("$"))
                return;

            var @event = EventSerialization.DeserializeEvent(resolvedEvent.OriginalEvent);
            if (@event != null)
            {
                var eventType = @event.GetType();
                if (_eventHandlerMapping.ContainsKey(eventType))
                {
                    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _eventHandlerMapping[eventType](event));
                    Console.WriteLine("The task is running asynchronously...");
                }
            }
            if (resolvedEvent.OriginalPosition != null) _latestPosition = resolvedEvent.OriginalPosition.Value;
        }

        private void HandleSubscriptionDropped(EventStoreCatchUpSubscription subscription, SubscriptionDropReason dropReason, Exception ex)
        {
            if (dropReason == SubscriptionDropReason.ProcessingQueueOverflow)
            {
                //TODO: Wait and reconnect probably with back off
            }

            if (dropReason == SubscriptionDropReason.UserInitiated)
                return;

            if (SubscriptionDropMayBeRecoverable(dropReason))
            {
                Start();
            }
        }

        private static bool SubscriptionDropMayBeRecoverable(SubscriptionDropReason dropReason)
        {
            return dropReason == SubscriptionDropReason.Unknown || dropReason == SubscriptionDropReason.SubscribingError ||
                   dropReason == SubscriptionDropReason.ServerError || dropReason == SubscriptionDropReason.ConnectionClosed;
        }

        private static void LiveProcessingStarted(EventStoreCatchUpSubscription eventStoreCatchUpSubscription)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

In your expert opinion, is this a valid approach? Could you please suggest any improvements?

PS:

Maybe:

```
Task.Run(() => _eventHandlerMapping[eventType](@event));
```

would be better?

Comment: I did not made a full review, but my first criticism would be to avoid a variable named "@event". Even it's perfectly legal with the @ prefix, it's ugly. Only useful for example for generated code against a datasource (db, ws...), not in "regular" code. I know, this is not really helpful concerning the main topic, sorry.

Comment: There is no such thing as .NET 5. The current version is .NET 4.5.2, and the upcoming version (Visual Studio 2015) is .NET 4.6. Are you confusing .NET version numbers and C# versions?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant - sorry.

Comment: Personally I find it hard to read the entire code, and figure out your intent. Can you please produce a smaller example, and be more specific about your question. Describe your current approach with few words, small example, and things you are wondering which could be improved / are issues.. etc..

Comment: @VikasGupta - it is fairly straightforward. If the subscriber's method is hit (EventOccured) I want to exploit the possibility of multiple cores via Task Parallelism. At the moment: Task.Run(() => _eventHandlerMapping[eventType](@event)); seems to be right.

Comment: Have you looked at Rx (https://rx.codeplex.com/). It may just be what you're looking for.

Comment: @Onots - thanks for that. I have indeed started to look at RX but am not yet sure how it would help in this particular scenario.

Comment: Instead of creating parallel event subscriber (complications and overhead) why not use normal event and process event handlers in parallel? Imho, you get more mistakes identifying if its a parallel event handler or not, than if you would have all events *normal*, but will be able to see their handler run coder in parallel. Does creating of it worth it?

Comment: @Sinatr - thanks. I have to admit that I do not fully understand. Can you please provide an answer?

Comment: Somehow funny to see the calls for a merge to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) deleted, for whatever reason ... These calls seem more than legit and a clear statement why they are not would clarify things dramatically!

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair - sorry this has nothing to do with me. I think you have a point ...

Comment: @csetzkorn That is the reason why I did not ping you directly ;) I suppose an administrator did some cleanup, but did not leave a true  and comprehensible reason ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a single `EventOccured` delegate which is where you'd be notified for all events that occur in the `EventStore`
First consider running the pre code inside `EventOccured` in a different dispatcher than the one on which the events are fired.
Secondly, would it be possible for you change this to a `abstract class` with implementation for `FakeEventBase` and then extend it and create individual instances for each `FakeEvent` type.
That would be much cleaner solution.
Thirdly, consider have a custom `ThreadScheduler` for queuing and running these `Handle` tasks.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(v=vs.110).aspx

EDIT:
I would have a broadcaster class like below which knows when the operation has completed and raises the finished event.

```
public class EventBroadcaster
{
    public event EventHandler SomeEventOccured;

    public async void DoLongRunningOperationAndRaiseFinishedEvent()
    {
        var waitingTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

        await waitingTask.ContinueWith(t => RaiseSomeEventOccured(), CancellationToken.None,
            TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Current);
    }

    private void RaiseSomeEventOccured()
    {
        EventHandler handler = SomeEventOccured;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

and then an EventListener

```
public class EventListner
{
    private readonly string _id;

    public EventListner(string id)
    {
        _id = id;
    }

    public void ListenTo(EventBroadcaster broadcaster)
    {
        broadcaster.SomeEventOccured += OnSomeEventOccured;
    }

    private async void OnSomeEventOccured(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("EventListner {0} received at {1}", _id,
            currentTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fffffff"));

        //Not required just to show this does not affect other instances.
        //await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }
}
```

then this would be the Program.cs for testing

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var broadcaster = new EventBroadcaster();

        var listners = new List<EventListner>();

        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var listner = new EventListner(i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            listner.ListenTo(broadcaster);
            listners.Add(listner);
        }

        broadcaster.DoLongRunningOperationAndRaiseFinishedEvent();

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for operation to complete");

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

In this example the handler delegates are fired one by one in the order they were subscribed to.

Now modify the code in the Broadcaster to something like below
Note:I have changed method signature from `EventHandler` to `Action` for ease of coding.

```
    private void RaiseSomeEventOccured()
    {
        Action handler = SomeEventOccured;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var parallelOption = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount };
            Parallel.Invoke(parallelOption, Array.ConvertAll(handler.GetInvocationList(), ConvertToAction));
            handler();
        }
    }

    private Action ConvertToAction(Delegate del)
    {
        return (Action)del;
    }
```

Now you will see that the events are fired in random order.
I got better performance using option 1.
Note: always with `TPL` and `Parallel` programming you need to make sure there is a benefit before going for it.

Comment: Sorry your answer does not make sense. Why should SomeEventSubscriber implement FakeEventBase? Also not sure why I should implement a tailor made ThreadScheduler in such a simple scenario ...

Comment: you want events to be handled in parallel if you have multiple listeners the events can be processed in parallel.
Image a traffic signal, there are multiple cars waiting in the signal for the `green light` and then all cars make their decision to move depending on the traffic before them; In your case `EventOccured` is not broadcasted to all handlers at the same time rather `EventOccured` dispatches them one by one albeit asynchronously hope you get the difference.

Comment: Also I suggested having a separate `ThreadPool` because I though you didn't want the even processing to be done in the main ThreadPool which might cause delay if the other ThreadPool already has tasks queued.

Comment: Can you please provide some alternative code to broadcast to all handlers at the same time?

Comment: Btw, I thought that async and await allow you to 'fire and forget events'. The async event handlers would then run in 'parallel' whilst exploiting the cores of the processor. Hence, firing of the next event is not delayed by handling the previously fired event ...

Comment: you are correct but there is a delay in firing in the control stack because there is only one handler and since you have not checked for thread integrity (`lock`) in your `EventOccured` method I assume firing happens one by one, if not you need to have a `lock` inside `EventOccured` in this implementation which would not give the parallel behavior you are expecting.

Comment: Ok can you please suggest an improvement on exactly this subject? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks that looks interesting. Could you please clarify what option 1 is? Also, the LongRunningOperation is, in my scenario, run in the event handler not before the event is fired. Basically, the broadcaster should fire the events parallel as quickly as possible and the eventhandlers (i.e. workers) should execute some computationally expensive stuff. Sorry if this was not clear.

Comment: option one was firing events in the order they were subscribed to without the `Parallel.Inoke`

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see a point in creating parallel event subscriber (if I understand your intention correct - to be able to run event handlers in parallel, not one after another as with *normal* events).

It's much more *clear* to express intent to run in parallel if event handler **itself** shows it.

Something like (very primitive).

```
void SomeEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
       ... // some code to run in parallel
    });
}
```

You may want to create sort of manager (honestly, I have no clue how to occupy all cores, but I don't think this is complicated, I just never have to do it), but please, keep normal events.

Comment: I guess your suggestions would exploit the cores if events come in very quickly for the particular eventhandler. This is in contrast to exploiting the cores at a higher level (i.e. in SomeEventSubscriber) as I have attempted. The question is what is more scalable ...